# How to compare multiple levels of data

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, biostatistics, post-hoc

I am trying to figure out which statistical test I need to use in order to compare my data. Basically, I had to asses cell viability in medias restricted in one amino acid. So, I had 19 different medias and performed a viability test. How do I compare each restricted media to each other? I used a one-way ANOVA that tells me that there is statistical difference between the means but I need to find out which means are statistically different. Thank you

Comment: If you did a standard one-factor ANOVA assuming variances are the same in each medium, then consider Tukey's HSD procedure. (But you might start by testing whether variances differ remarkably among media.) // If you did a Welch one-factor ANOVA in which variances need not all be equal, consider a Bonferroni procedure. // You might get more useful answers if you say which type of ANOVA you did, what P-value led you to believe media differ, and whether you had an idea in advance which media might differ.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply. I did a standard one -way ANOVA and the p-value was 0.000061 which is quite significant. I had no idea in advance about the differences in media. I thought about doing a Tukey's analysis but wasn't sure that woud be the correct test.

Comment: With 19 levels (media) of the factor, you potentially have ${19 \choose 2} = 171$ pairs of levels to compare. If you were to test all of those at the 5% level you would expect 8 or 9 "significant" differences--even if none exist. So you clearly need to control the "family error rate" in order to prevent "false discovery" of differences among media. Tukey's HSD procedure is one common way to do that. // However, both the original ANOVA and Tukey's HSD procedure are based on the assumption that media have equal population variances, so check for that first.